# How to combine row in table like this more simpler

Tags: html, css, html-table, row, request-headers

[image]

This is my code: How can I create table like pic above more simply. I try to use `thead` `tr` and `th` but it is not affected.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <h4> Danh Sách Khách Hàng (Table Basic, Table Hover)</h4>
    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered text-center">
      <tbody>    
        <tr style="font-weight: bold;background-color: green;font-size: 20px;color:red">
            <td class="middle" style="border-right:none;">Day</td>
            <td class="middle" rowspan="2" style="border-right:none;border-left: none;">2</td>      
            <td class="middle" rowspan="2" style="border-right:none;border-left: none;">3</td>
            <td class="middle" rowspan="2" style="border-right:none;border-left: none;">4</td>
            <td class="middle" rowspan="2" style="border-right:none;border-left: none;">5</td>
            <td class="middle" rowspan="2" style="border-right:none;border-left: none;">6</td>
            <td class="middle" rowspan="2" style="border-right:none;border-left: none;">7</td>
            <td class="middle" rowspan="2" style="border-right:none;border-left: none;">CN</td                  
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td class="middle">Course</td>                      
        </tr>    
        <tr>
            <td class="middle">AA</td>
            <td class="middle">x</td>       
            <td class="middle"></td>        
            <td class="middle">x</td>       
            <td class="middle"></td>        
            <td class="middle"></td>        
            <td class="middle"></td>        
            <td class="middle"></td>    
        </tr>   
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the css?

Comment: The code looks like a good start, so I'm not sure what the problem is.